# Can I change the state of Github Issue? Open > Needs Verification > Closed

Tags: github

It would be really great to have a Github issue be in an intermediary "Resolved" state before I close the issue.

Right now, I have a "Resolved" label and I manually select the issue and change it's label on the web after I commit. Is there a way I can do this from the commit message?

I am sure this is a common problem. How do you guys solve this?

I have never used Github API but can this be done using the API If I were to do this myself?

Comment: i think git doesn't support this feature

Comment: What exactly is the difference betweeen “Resolved” and “Closed”?

Comment: Resolved - when dev thinks the issue must be tested and then closed

Comment: BitBucket supports this feature to an extent, but Github doesn't

Comment: This seems to be possible using GitHub API. Take a look here:https://github.com/joshrendek/github-postcommit-shinies

Answer (score 10):

Since September 14, 2016 you could manage your states with projects. See image below:

[image]

Reference and source: [GitHub - A whole new GitHub Universe: announcing new tools, forums, and features](https://github.com/blog/2256-a-whole-new-github-universe-announcing-new-tools-forums-and-features).

I know it's not like a new state like "needs verification" because you can't like @NevikRehnel said in his answer. But you could make a column named "open", "needs verification" and "closed" and all the issues can you list in correct column.

Comment: Is there a way to move from one column to another when a branch is created with that issue ID as a prefix (example: `Ready` to `In progress`)?

Comment: @user1046: I don't know. Long thime ago when I used GitHub. You can check it on the documentation of GitHub.

Comment: Just checked with GitHub support and they told me it is not possible at the moment, just passed it as a feedback. Is there any specific alternative for managing the GitHub issues (in the form of a board) that you would recommend ?

Answer (score 4):

No, Github issues only support two states (open and closed). Any other "states" must be realized via labels, as you are already doing right now.
And as of right now, there is no way to apply labels from commit messages.

You can always request such features from Github support of course, and they might be implemented at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this problem using this method : [Adding and reassigning github issues via commit message](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/adding-labels-and-re-assigning-github-issues-via-commit-message/).

A simple ruby script will run on each commit, and check the commit message looking for `~myLabel` and `=assignedMember` to update correctly the issue.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: which makes sense - cause his link doesnt work any more :)